# why my thread not working continuously

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, network-programming, tcpclient

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;


namespace MultiClientServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpListener listner = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000));
            listner.Start();
            textBox1.Text += "Started TCP Server"+Environment.NewLine;
            listner.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(Accept), listner);
        }

        void Accept(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    textBox1.Text += "Client Request Arrived" + Environment.NewLine;
                }));
            TcpListener listner1 = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
            TcpClient client = listner1.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
            textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    textBox1.Text += "Client Request Approved" + Environment.NewLine;
                }));
            Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ContinueRcv));
            th.Start(client);
        }

        void ContinueRcv(object obj)
        {
            TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    textBox1.Text += sr.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

i was trying to make this app so that when a client is connected than a new thread will b created and it will b in continue receive.. bt it is not unfortunately.. plz give me solution using this code.. mean it is not a class requirement or anything.. i jux want to know how to do this in this or any related way..

Comment: 'client' and 'sr' should not be accessed from the recv thread as a member of the form class, to start with. You need to pass 'client' to the thread at the time of thread creation, else it could easily get overwritten by another incoming accept.  'sr' should be a local in the thread for similar reason.

Comment: got it.. let me check this..

Comment: i have checked no change to code.. i can do thix with while true in my thread bt i dont think that is a good practice.. do u have any idea..??

Comment: @rummykhan: The method `ContinueRcv` causes one line to be read and that's it. I don't see any loops in there, so why would it continue doing its stuff?

Comment: because its a thread.. i think i need to recheck my thread understanding.. thanx for the comment.. bt tell me one thing if it is not in while (true) loop it will execute for once only.. ?

Comment: Rather than starting a thread that does blocking I/O on the client, call [Client.GetStream().BeginRead()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread(v=vs.110).aspx) to start an asynchronous read. When you're done processing that read, you issue another asynchronous read request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread is not something that is being called continuously, your code in the thread block need to be called continuously, since your thread is responsible of calling `ContinueRcv` the thread ends with the end of this method,

If you want to continuously receive the data from `Stream` you need to call StreamReader's ReadLine() in some infinite loop,

```
void ContinueRcv(object obj)
{
    TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    while (true) 
    {
        if ( !connection ) { // when connection closed, abort, terminated
            break;
        }
        msg = sr.ReadLine();
        textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            textBox1.Text += msg  + Environment.NewLine;
        }));
    }
}
```

Remember to break the loop when connection closed,